# pandas: extend dataframe and increase indices automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a `DataFrame` with a monotonically increasing index, e.g.

```
     values
100    10
200    9
300    15
400    7
```

I'd like to extend it by copying the last value, and automatically continue the indices (or perhaps by supplying the step, that's still fine):

```
     values
100    10
200    9
300    15
400    7
500    7
600    7
700    7
```

At the moment I'm creating a new DataFrame with just the new values (and the new indices) and I'm using `new.combine_first(old)`. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Does `df.loc[df.index[-1] + 100] = df['values'][-1]` work for you?

Comment: `for _ in range(n):
    df.loc[df.index[-1] + 100] = df.iloc[-1]`
seems to work. Is this the ultimate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a new index via

```
index = 100 * pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=7)
```

and use it to reindex your DataFrame and fill the created NaN values with forwardfill.

```
df = df.reindex(index).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: That's nice! Changes the dtype though (from `int` to `float`), not sure if that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether that is any better than what you have at the moment but it leads to the desired output:

```
index_delta = df.index[-1] - df.index[-2]

max_index = 700

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'values': df.values[-1]}, index=range(df.index[-1], max_index + index_delta, index_delta))

print(pd.concat([df, df2]))
```

yields:

```
     values
100      10
200       9
300      15
400       7
400       7
500       7
600       7
700       7
```